# Commutator of linear operators

Tags: operator-theory, noncommutative-algebra

Show that if $ A B - B A = \Id $,  $ A , B : X \to X $ ($ X $ is a normed space) linear operators, then either $ A $ or $ B $ is unbounded.

I am not sure how to approach this, because I've never worked with commutators. I have to show that $ \frac { \| B x \| _ X } { \| x \| _ X } $ is unbounded.
My Idea: $ 1 = \frac { \| \Id ( x ) \| _ X } { \| x \| _ X } = \frac { \| ( A B - B A ) x \| _ X } { \| x \| _ X } $ But this leads to nothing. I am very thankful for hints.

Greetings.

Comment: A quite different but still clearly related question (absolutely no hint):
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2339701/solution-to-functional-identity-in-two-variables

Comment: If $ X $ is finite-dimensional, then taking trace of both sides gives you $ 0 = \dim X $, which is only true when $ X $ is the zero space. Thus otherwise $ X $ must be infinite-dimensional.

Answer (score 0):

Since, there is a bit of interest. I decided to post my solution.

Given $AB-BA=\mathbb{1}_X$, assume $\|A\|,\|B\| \le C$
, one can show that $AB^n-B^nA=nB^{n-1}$ per induction.

Taking norm on the equation

$$|n|\|B^{n-1}\|=\|AB^n-B^nA\| \le \|A\|\|B^n\|+\|B^n\|\|A\|= 2 \|A\| \|B^n\|$$
since (showing via induction) $B^{n-1} \ne 0 $
$$\implies n \le 2 \|A\|\|B\|$$
for arbitary $n$ this is impossible due to Archimedes' principle. Therefore one Operator is unbounded.